# ¿Por que este programa no se ejecuta correctamente?

Tags: bucles, sl

Estuve haciendo un programa en SLE2 que dice lo siguiente:
**Escribir un programa que determine la cantidad de combinaciones que se pueden realizar tomando k elementos distintos de un grupo de n elementos. El numero de combinaciones esta dado por la siguiente formula:**
**[image: texto en negrita]** Donde m! factorial representa el factorial de m

Yo hice el código utilizando subrutinas, pero no me está dando los valores que deseo. Ya que, en la subrutina tengo un ciclo iterativo que me aumenta el valor de forma automática para obtener los factoriales, hacer la operación y saber las combinaciones...

Cuando ejecuto el código no me hace el factorial de los valores que ingreso. Si ingreso 4 debería sacar el factorial de ese número y no lo hace. Necesito ayuda para este problema, por favor.

```
var 

n, k, comb : numerico

inicio 

    cls()

    n = 0
    k = 0
    comb = 0

    imprimir ("Ingrese el valor de n: ")
    leer(n)

    imprimir ("Ingrese el valor de k: ")
    leer(k)

    comb = fact(n)/(fact(k)*fact(n-k))

    imprimir ("Cantidad de combinaciones: ", comb)
fin 

subrutina fact(n : numerico) retorna numerico 

var
factorial : numerico 
inicio 
    factorial = 1
    repetir
        factorial = factorial * n
    hasta (n > 0)
    retorna(factorial)
fin
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto no es pseudocodigo.. es pseint no? y tu problema es: hasta (n > 0)... si pusiste eso,va a salir de una.. tu condicion es cuando lo hagas n veces... es un for, no un while...

Comment: Si. es PSeInt. Un ciclo 'mientras' no se podria utilizar? a parte de 'desde-hasta'. Porque como busco que lo haga n veces, en 'mientras' puedo darle una condicion que lo aumente. Solo para aclarar

Comment: Si es pseint, entonces no es pseudocodigo, es pseint ;)... nose que es un ciclo mientras... si es mientras un valor i sea menor que n, entonces si.. es eso.. vos queres que esto se ejecute n veces.. no?

Comment: ah no.. vos queres el factorial.. el factorial de un numero es el numero multiplicado por el anterior, hasta llegar a 1.. obviamente ahi nunca estas restando 1 a n... esta mal tu definicion de factorial...

Comment: ¿Pero es Pseint o SLE2? ¿Por qué pones Pseint? NO son lo mismo. Con pseint lo puedes hacer de [esta manera](https://pastebin.com/djbHyUQh).

Comment: En realidad es SLE2. Me equivoque desde el principio. Pido disculpas, y gracias por el aporte ya tengo una idea clara de como solucionar el problemas por ambos softwares

Comment: El error está en el repetir de la función factorial. primero tiene que haber otra variable i definida dentro del factorial e inicializada en 1 e incrementada dentro del repetir. Lo otro es el condicional, tiene que ser hasta i > n

Comment: @AlejandroCaro si haces ediciones, _no toques el código_, esté bien o no. Esto es motivo de rechazo de la edición.

Answer (score 0):

Función factorial implementada en lenguaje Sl

```
subrutina fact(n : numerico) retorna numerico 
var
    factorial, i: numerico 
inicio 
    factorial = 1
    i = 1
    repetir
        factorial = factorial * i
        i = i + 1
    hasta (i > n)
    retorna(factorial)
fin
```